# Images doesn't get reflected from drawables-ldrtl when locale changed to Arabic in Android

Tags: android

I'm developing an app which has multi language support. I have added Arabic language too. I changed locale to Arabic programmatically but images doesn't get picked from drawables-ldrtl folder that I've created for RTL support. Following are the configurations I did to set locale:

```
Resources res = getResources();
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
Locale myLocale = new Locale(locales[0],locales[1]);
conf.locale = myLocale;
res.updateConfiguration(conf, res.getDisplayMetrics());

    View  view = getWindow().getDecorView();

    //supporting RTL
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1 && myLocale.getLanguage().equals("ar")){//Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1 = 17
        view.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
    }
```

Anybody who knows how to solve it please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: just use `recreate()` to recreate the whole page

Comment: I'm relaunching the whole app when locale changes. Still I need to use recreate() ?

Comment: how do you relaunch the app? recreate is relaunching app also, do you use intent?

Comment: Yes, I'm relaunching app using intent.

Comment: try to use recreate instead. this will just fix i think

Comment: No its not working.

Comment: if this is not working, try to set the imageView dynamically, after recreate() use imageView.setImageDrawable or any method to set again the image

Comment: Is there no way to reflect these changes in XML? As I can't do it dynamically as there are 50-60 places.